# macOS Monterey Heroku CLI error when running remote command

Tags: macos, heroku, elixir, heroku-cli, macos-monterey

I'm trying to run this command in a Heroku deployed application:

```
heroku run 'POOL_SIZE=2 iex -S mix' -a name-of-the-app
```

And after waiting like a minute or so I get this error:

[image: error]

I found [this](https://twissmueller.medium.com/resolving-the-problem-of-port-5000-already-being-in-use-dd2fe4bad0be) article and already disabled the AirPlay Receiver but the issue keeps happening.

This is the error I get in the application logs:

[image: heroku error]

I'm using an M1 Pro macOS Monterey 12.1 with the Heroku CLI on the latest version installed via `brew`

Comment: Heroku is having issues at the moment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2398

Comment: I don't think it's related to that since it's been happening to me for the last two weeks.